# std::ctype::narrow segmentation fault with utf-8 locale

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to better understand the regular expression scanner implementation (`std::__details::_Scanner<>`) in `<regex>` on g++ (GCC) 4.9.2 (Linux).

Running the scanner in the POSIX locale worked fine. However, when I switched to a UTF-8 locale, I started getting segmentation fault in `std::ctype::narrow`.

Some sample code which reproduces what happens in the scanner is shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

typedef std::ctype<char> CTYPE;

int
main ()
{
  const char* p;
  const char* s = "asdb";
  const CTYPE& ctype(std::use_facet<CTYPE>(std::locale("POSIX")));

  for (p = s; *p != '\0'; ++p)
  {
    char ch = ctype.narrow(*p,'\0');
    std::cout << *p << ": " << (int) ch << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Setting to locale to "en_GB.UTF-8" instead of "POSIX" (on Linux) causes a segmentation fault.

Is this a bug or have a missed something fundamental (my experience with C++ is limited and my experience with anything related to locales on C++ is practically non-existent)?

**Update:**

The problem code is this (`/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/locale_facets.h`):

```
char
narrow(char_type __c, char __dfault) const
{
  if (_M_narrow[static_cast<unsigned char>(__c)])
    return _M_narrow[static_cast<unsigned char>(__c)];
  const char __t = do_narrow(__c, __dfault);
  if (__t != __dfault)
    _M_narrow[static_cast<unsigned char>(__c)] = __t;
  return __t;
}
```

There appear to be a number of issues:

- For locales other than POSIX (UTF8 or otherwise), the `_M_narrow` mapping table returns jiberish (e.g. `french` locale returns a `'` for `a`).
- When the `_M_narrow` entry is zero and `do_narrow` gets called, it seems that the corresponding vtable entry is invalid, as the faulting instruction is `callq %rax` (mostly NULL but occasionally some random value).

So I'll mark this one down to a GCC or libstd++ bug.

Comment: If you `locale -a`, does en_GB.UTF-8 exist?

Comment: It is the default locale on the system I am using. `locale -a` lists "en_GB.utf8", tried that too, same result (segfault).

Comment: Locales are a strange afterthought in C++, so it wouldn't be surprising if there's some bug. You should be able to get more debug information on where in `narrow` the segfault is, though.

Comment: Are you sure your segfault isn't really an assertion or uncaught exception?

Comment: I encountered the same seg fault location.  In the end the `narrow` was just a symptom, the actual cause in my case was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382355/stdregex-and-dual-abi/51385122.  The fix turned out to be compile without `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`.